# Detect if App was Launched From Tapping Local Notification Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I would like to know how to detect if my app was launched from the user tapping a local notification.

I am currently using the method `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` My app correctly detects that the app was launched from a notification with this method only when the app is in still active. If I end the app by swiping it up in the app switcher, then tapping on a notification opens the app but does not register in the `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.

I previously set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate` to `self` in `viewDidLoad()`. Some people said to set it in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` instead, and I tried that like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    return true
}
```

However, the issue remains.

**My Question:** How do I detect if my app was launched from the user tapping a local notification, whether the app is active or inactive?

Swift version: swift 5
Xcode version: Xcode 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `options` for your scene delegate `willConnect` method or (if there is no scene delegate) your app delegate `willFinishLaunching` method. This tells you how you got launched.

Comment: By saying "`willConnect` method" do you mean the `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method?

Comment: Yes. If you have a scene delegate, that method is called at launch time, and the `options` object will contain a non-nil `notificationResponse` if you were launched by the user interacting with a notification.